# Why is there no association between boundary, control and entity classes?

Tags: class, uml

I am currently learning about OOAD, and systems analysis and design. I recently read that there should be no association between boundary, control and entity classes and I was just wondering why this is? The text didn't specify.

Answer (score 3):

That's simply not true.

These classes give high to middle-level abstraction of the system structure and they surely have relationships in between. Look here for an example of the related pattern and common connectivity patterns:

http://epf.eclipse.org/wikis/openuppt/openup_basic/guidances/concepts/entity_control_boundary_pattern,_uF-QYEAhEdq_UJTvM1DM2Q.html

BTW, these classes are somehow obsolete and not so much used in UML 2.5. For the same perspective and semantics, use components with stereotypes (boundary, control, entity).
You can enrich them with corresponding interfaces and connect via dependencies. This is a great tool for architecting your system.